# Xamarin PCL - Making API calls based on user entry, how to dampen requests?

Tags: c#, .net, search, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have a search task that makes a request to an API, within a portable class library, when the user enters text in the textbox, this works as expected but I have a concern over performance at scale. When we have a large userbase all making requests to this API on every key press I can foresee performance issues.

I have limited the API call to only fire when there are more than three valid characters but I want to dampen this further. I could implement a timer over the top of this but it does not feel like a good solution and is not present in the PCL framework.

Is there a recommended pattern to achieve this type of request dampening?

```
    private async Task GetClubs()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ClubSearch) && ClubSearch.Replace(" ", "").Length >= 3)
            {
                Clubs = await dataService.GetClubs(ClubSearch);
            }
        }
        catch (DataServiceException ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why timer does not feel good?

Comment: @Evk A timer implementation just feels a little hacky to me. It's kind of a moot topic as I need this to work in a Portable Class Library which does not include a timer implementation. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: And Task.Delay is available at least?

Comment: @Evk. Good idea, hadn't considered that. Please create an answer and I will accept it as the correct method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that is done with timer. When search text changes you start (or reuse) a timer which will fire after delay and execute search request. If more text is typed during that delay - timer is reset. Sample code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    const int ThrottlePeriod = 500; // ms
    public MyClass() {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
            ExecuteRequest();
        }, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private string _searchTerm;
    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get { return _searchTerm; }
        set
        {
            _searchTerm = value;
            ResetTimer();
        }
    }

    private void ResetTimer() {
        _timer.Change(ThrottlePeriod, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void ExecuteRequest() {
        Console.WriteLine(SearchTerm);
    }
}
```

If timer is not available, you can do the same with Task.Delay:

```
public class MyClass
{        
    const int ThrottlePeriod = 500; // ms
    private string _searchTerm;
    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get { return _searchTerm; }
        set
        {
            _searchTerm = value;
            SearchWithDelay();              
        }
    }

    private async void SearchWithDelay() {
        var before = this.SearchTerm;
        await Task.Delay(ThrottlePeriod);
        if (before == this.SearchTerm) {
            // did not change while we were waiting
            ExecuteRequest();
        }
    }        

    private void ExecuteRequest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SearchTerm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheap/Fast way to implement this is a `Task.Delay`:

```
var mySearchThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (async delegate {
   while (true) {
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seachText) {
          YourSearchMethod(seachText)
       };

       InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
          // Refresh your datasource on the UIthread
       });

       await Task.Delay (2000);
   }
})).Start ();
```

A PCL-based solution (and amazing clean way with a **great framework**) is to use `ReactiveUI` throttling **(`Throttle`)**, then you can do feats like:

```
// Throttle searching to every 2 seconds
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
    .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .InvokeCommand(SearchCommand)
```

---

Ref: http://reactiveui.net

Ref: http://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/when-any/index.html

Comment: Won't that just execute request to service every 2 seconds?

Comment: @Evk Yes, based on when you choose to exit `while (true)` (i.e, as long as the SearchBar is present) every 2 seconds filter your datasource if the search text has changed and update the Ui... cheap/fast.. but I greatly prefer to use `Command` throttling within `ReactiveUI` and tie this into my search ViewModel

Comment: Even without commands and stuff there is a better way to use Task.Delay and not constantly poll service with useless requests every 2 seconds. And what if I left for a lunch and left input field focused?

Comment: @Evk Your assumption is that your data is static, my assumption is that is not (dynamic data and reactive ui as this typically would be a mobile app) . Again, `fast/cheap`... your answer would have to be adapted with a binding to a dynamic data source to place your logic into a wash/rinse/report pattern, either way, if the search text is changed and check for data changes, update the data filter, update the UI...

Comment: I do not assume data is static - I assume user types his search request and want to only execute it when user stopped typing (just like reactive extensions do for you in your second example). You on the other hand (in first example) will just execute it at random points, and even if he does not type anything at all. It is not related to reactive ui, commands, or whatever modern terms you might use - it's just bad code which should never be used in real applications.